# Truth table probability

Tags: probability

Let's say we have a truth table (AND) like this:

```
A B
F F = F
T F = F
F T = F
T T = T
```

Where A and B are 2 coins that randomly can be True or False (the two faces).
So now I throw the two coins, what is the probability to get True on both?

During an interview I just said 1/4 but they said that it's wrong, it is 3/4 and right now I'm lost.

Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have misremembered the problem or something like that, you are right and they are wrong.  3/4 would be right for OR.